# fscanf doesn't assign values ​correctly in c

Tags: c, scanf

I've a txt file like this:

```
milk l 300
oil  l 200
..
```

and my fuction is the following (some variables are global, some words are in italian):

```
void Calcola() {
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("ingredients_out.txt", "r");

float somma = 0.0;
int i;

char ingredient[15]; //this is the problem
char simbolo[1];
float quantita;

while(fscanf(fp, "%s%s%f", ingredient, simbolo, &quantita) == 3){   
    printf("%s\n", ingredient); //I think the problem is here
    if(simbolo[0] != 'g') {
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if(strcmp(V[i].ingrediente, ingredient) == 0) {
                somma += quantita * V[i].peso;
            }
        }
    }
}
fclose(fp);
printf("Somma pesi: %d\n", somma);
}
```

The problem is that "ingredient" variable is always empty, it's a series of blank spaces..Why?

Comment: `char simbolo[1];` as a C-string this can only hold a null terminator, so it's basically useless. Maybe change this to `char simbolo;` and use `%c` in the `fscanf`.

Comment: or better write `char simbolo[2]` to have an empty position for the terminating null...

Comment: @SergeBallesta You'd need to use `%1s` so it doesn't write past the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite interesting. So the reason is actually because `simbolo[1]` does not have enough storage to hold a C string (i.e strings terminated with a `\0`). But what does that have to do with `ingredient` being blank?

Well, if you look carefully, the very first character of `ingredient` during the first read (i.e reading "milk") is a null terminator, then `i`, then `l`, then `k`. WAIT! How did that `\0` get where `m` should have been?

The answer? Buffer overflow.

`fscanf` first puts "milk" into `ingredient`, as it should. Then it *tried* to put `"l"` into the `simbolo` (note `"l"` is actually `l` and `\0`) and it does that rightfully. But wait, `simbolo` can only hold one character. So it holds the `l`, what the heck happened to the `\0`?

You guessed it. Due to stack alignment on modern architectures, the `ingredient` memory begins right after the end of `simbolo`. So `\0` is actually put in `ingredient[0]` and boom you have just wrecked that memory.

This is a pretty textbook definition of undefined behavior associated with buffer overflow. Don't expect this to happen in every single machine. But I'm pretty sure this is what's happening on *your* machine.

So yeah, the fix is to just do `char simbolo[2]` if you want that `l` as a string. Or if you're certain it's always a singular character, simply do `char simbolo` and use `%c` on the `fscanf`

Edit: Also as mentioned by @Barmar, `%s` with `simbolo[2]` alone won't save you unless you're certain of the length in the input file and you 100% trust it. If you insist on using `%s`, also mention a `n` in `%ns` where `n` is the amount of characters (excluding null terminator) your buffer can hold.

Comment: If you're not certain that it's always a single character, `[2]` won't be big enough, either. It has to be 1+ the longest possible value.

Comment: And when using `%c` they should have a space before it. Otherwise it will put the space into `simbolo`.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks a lot friend! 
You were really accurate!

Comment: @Barmar very good points! `%s` alone is definitely not safe

Comment: You can use `%1s` to prevent overflow, but if the word is longer than 1 character it won't read the following `float`.